# How can i attached multiple documents in javascript mailto?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

We need to attached multiple document in mail to in by using JavaScript or j query.

We need to attached my document path must be live URI Like:
http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf

My Code is Like:
HTML:

```
<a onclick="sendmaildocument();">Mail</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function sendmaildocument()
{   
   document.location = "mailto:user@example.com?attach="+"http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf";
}
```

Please help me..!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not add an attachment to a message with the mailto: URL scheme.
mailto: only supports header values or text/plain content. See 
[RFC 2368](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html) for details.

Comment: Right, So i there any other option to attached document in mail by using  JavaScript, j query or Ajax?

Comment: javascript and jquery can't send mail with attachment. With Ajax you can call a PHP page, take a look to this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12302354/2298792)